# Magento edit navigation structure

Tags: magento, navigation

Need to add 'div' tag in level-top. I'm tried to edit it in block/navigation.php, but no result.
http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_9kb.1394883580.png

Comment: Where is `block/navigation.php`?  Do you mean .phtml?  What is the full path to the file you're trying to edit?

Comment: No it's not a template.It's a block, what makes menu in template. the full path is:

Comment: No it's not a template. It's a block, what to makes menu in template. the full path is: /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php .To change template in /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml does not fit me, because the part what I need to change is in $_menu.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` so you're not editing the core.

Open `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php` and look for `protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml` (around line 218).

Look for the following code:

```
    // assemble list item with attributes
    $htmlLi = '<li';
    foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
        $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
    }
    $htmlLi .= '>';
```

and replace with:

```
    // assemble list item with attributes
    $htmlLi = '<li';
    foreach ($attributes as $attrName => $attrValue) {
        $htmlLi .= ' ' . $attrName . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $attrValue) . '"';
    }
    $htmlLi .= '>';

    if ($level==0) { 
         $htmlLi .= '<div>';
    }
```

Look for:

```
   $html[] = '</li>';
```

and change it to:

```
   if ($level==0) { 
        $html[] = '</div></li>';
   } else {
        $html[] = '</li>';
   }
```